# Next.js project works locally but throw an error on the server

Tags: next.js, frontend, client-side

The project works fine when run locally. But when I deploy it to the server with docker, some components give an error like "Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information)." as shown in the screenshot. Does anyone know how I can solve this and what exactly is causing it? Is it a Docker related issue?

(Note: There are no details about the error in the console, it just says there is an error. Or I didn't understand anything.)

[server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4S8A.png)
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onev5.png)

(Link on console: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/client-side-exception-occurred)

I tried to run the project on the server without any problem, but on some pages I get an error as you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: check the docker logs